Vulkan accesses wrong data when bindings of two shaders are identical
I have an issue where Vulkan uses the wrong descriptor set in my second draw call.
For simplicity, I'm using a single frame in flight. I have two descriptor sets allocated from the same descriptor pool and with the same descriptor set layout.
The vertex shader is the same for both my draw calls:
cbuffer RenderMatrizes : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 localToClipMatrix; // (model * view * projection)
};

struct VertexInput
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexOutput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexOutput main(VertexInput input)
{
    VertexOutput output;
    output.position = mul(localToClipMatrix, float4(input.position, 1.0));
    output.uv = input.uv;
    return output;
}

In the fragment shader, the only difference is the usage of Texture2D vs TextureCube.
This setup is only for testing.
First draw call:
SamplerState colorSampler : register(s10);
Texture2D colorMap : register(t20);

struct FragmentInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 main(FragmentInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float2 uv = input.uv.xy;
    return colorMap.Sample(colorSampler, uv);
}

Second draw call:
SamplerState colorSampler : register(s10);
TextureCube cubeMap : register(t20);

struct FragmentInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 main(FragmentInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float2 uv = input.uv.xy;
    return cubeMap.Sample(colorSampler, normalize(float3(uv, 1.0f)));
}

As long as the bindings of the colorMap and cubeMap are different, e.g., t20 and t21, I get no errors or warnings from the validation layers. However, if I use the same bindings as shown in the above code I get this validation layer error message:
Validation layer   ERROR: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdDraw-viewType-07752 ] Object 0: handle = 0x7e9cfd000000054b, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET; Object 1: handle = 0x77126e00000002c8, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW; | MessageID = 0x73ed4ff5 | vkCmdDraw():  the descriptor VkDescriptorSet 0x7e9cfd000000054b[] [Set 0, Binding 20, Index 0, variable "cubeMap"] ImageView type is VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D but the OpTypeImage has (Dim = Cube) and (Arrayed = 0). The Vulkan spec states: If a VkImageView is accessed as a result of this command, then the image view's viewType must match the Dim operand of the OpTypeImage as described in Instruction/Sampler/Image View Validation (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.290.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdDraw-viewType-07752)

Breakdown of the error message:
VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET = 0x7e9cfd000000054b (descriptor set of the first draw call)
the descriptor set [Set 0, Binding 20, Index 0, variable "cubeMap"] (problem when accessing this)

However, this makes no sense. I validated that the descriptor set 0x7e9cfd000000054b is the one used for the first draw call that uses the colorMap in Binding 20. So why is it trying to access the variable cubeMap, which is referenced by the other descriptor set?
In my render loop, I update all required data correctly, if I'm not mistaken:
vkCmdBindPipeline(...);
vkCmdPushConstants(...);

vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(...);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(...);

vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(...);
vkCmdDrawIndexed(...);

Sorry for not showing more code. All these concepts are very cumbersome, and I think reading through the entire code base and my personal abstractions is too much to ask for.
The basic problem should be discussable on a more fundamental level. If more information is required, I will gladly provide more details/code.
To me, the most confusing thing is that everything is working fine as long as I don't reuse the binding numbers across multiple shaders, which is an annoying workaround.
